# Serving media files in a remote server and app in another server in django

Tags: django, fabric

How can I serve or upload (uploading files from the website) media files to a remote server. One way would be ssh using fabric. But Using it I can transfer the files from one host to the remote host in case of static files (as in documentation). But is it possible that, whenever a user uploads a file in the website, it goes directly to the remote server

e.g. instead of file going to

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/usr/files/'
```

on the same server, it will go to folder located in remote server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried this solution:

https://github.com/aaugustin/django-resto

it has three modes of working according to the docs:

> **HybridStorage**
>
> With this backend, django-resto will run all file storage operations
>   on MEDIA_ROOT first, then replicate them to the media servers.
>
> **AsyncStorage**
>
> With this backend, django-resto will run all file storage operations
>   on MEDIA_ROOT and lanch their replication to the media servers in the
>   background. See Asynchronous operation.
>
> **DistributedStorage**
>
> With this backend, django-resto will only store the files on the media
>   servers. See Low concurrency situations.

And the servers that listen for incoming content can be a lighthttp implementation on nginx, as the docs recommend:

> Here is an example of lighttpd config:
>
> server.modules += (   "mod_webdav", )
>   $HTTP["remoteip"] ~= "^192.168.0.[0-9]+$" {   "webdav.activate = "enable" }
>
> Here is an example of nginx config, assuming the server was
>   compiled --with-http_dav_module:

```
 server {
     listen 192.168.0.10;
     location / {
         root /var/www/media;
         dav_methods PUT DELETE;
         create_full_put_path on;
         dav_access user:rw group:r all:r;
         allow 192.168.0.1/24;
         deny all;
     } 
  }
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Not supported anymore :(

Comment: 'django-resto' is deprecated, it's not maintained :(

Comment: I should probably update the 8years old answer, but nowdays everything is S3 Buckets, kubernetes, ephermal... Kinda feels as if the question belongs in a different time.

Comment: @BojanJovanovic AWS S3 buckets are expensive than a bare metal vps. Yes , you get a trial, but after that, you end up with a bill of more than 3000$. It would be better if there was any way to set up a remote server to do this now.. If you know how to do it, then please update the answer. Thanks in advance.